# java servlet: request parameter contains plus

Tags: java, servlets

The request parameter is like `decrypt?param=5FHjiSJ6NOTmi7/+2tnnkQ==`.

In the servlet, when I try to print the parameter by `String param = request.getParameter("param");` I get `5FHjiSJ6NOTmi7/ 2tnnkQ==`. It turns the character `+` into a space. How can I keep the orginal paramter or how can I properly handle the character `+`.

Besides, what else characters should I handle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two choices

### URL encode the parameter

If you have control over the generation of the URL you should [choose this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding).  If not...

### Manually retrieve the parameter

If you can't change how the URL is generated (above) then you can manually retrieve the raw URL.  [Certain methods decode parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966077/java-reading-undecoded-url-from-servlet) for you.  `getParameter` is one of them.  On the other hand, `getQueryString` does not decode the String.  If you have only a few parameters it shouldn't be difficult to [parse the value yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902090/how-to-extract-parameters-from-a-given-url).

```
request.getQueryString();
//?param=5FHjiSJ6NOTmi7/+2tnnkQ==
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the '+' character in a URL you need to encode it when it is generated. For '+' the correct encoding is %2b

Comment: Sorry got hung up on the space rather than the +. I'll fix my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use URLEncoder,URLDecoder's static methods for encoding and decoding URLs.

For example : - 
Encode the URL param using

```
    URLEncoder.encode(url,"UTF-8")
```

Back in the server side , decode this parameter using

```
    URLDecoder.decode(url,"UTF-8")
```

decode method returns a String type of the decoded URL.

Comment: In servlets, there's never a need to URL-decode a `request.getParameter()`. The container does that all by itself.

Comment: My bad. Thanks BalusC

Answer (score 0):

Allthough the question is some years old, I'd like to write down how I fixed the problem in my case: the download link to a file is created in a GWT page where

```
com.google.gwt.http.client.URL.encode(finalurl)
```

is used to encode the URL.
The problem was that the "+" sign a customer of us had in the filename wasn't encoded/escaped. So I had to remove the URL.encode(finalurl) and encode each parameter in the url with

```
URL.encodePathSegment(fileName)
```

I know my question is bound to GWT but it seems, URLEncoder.encode(string, encoding) should be applied to the parameter only aswell.