# Java- Servlet URL omitting plus sign in parameters

Tags: java, servlets

I have Servlet URL like **`GetServlet?clientTimeZone=GMT+00:00`** but while getting parameter in doPOst Method like

```
String ctz=request.getParameter( "clientTimeZone" );
```

I am getting only **`GMT 00:00`** i,e plus sign omitted. But I need that timezone along with plus sign.

Thanks

Comment: my be you can use **`%2B`** instead of **`+`**

Comment: Please check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19302375/java-servlet-request-parameter-contains-plus

Answer (score 0):

You can replace "+" with "%2B" while passing it in the URL.